# Why does OneDrive - Person appear twice in MS Word's "Save As" dialog?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, windows-8.1, onedrive

Here is the Save As dialog in MS Word 2013 running on Windows 8.1 with Update. **One Drive - Personal** appears twice. Why is that?

The first listing of it allows me to browse my files and to save. The second listing tells me that, "To connect to OneDrive - Personal, you will need your username and password. Sign in". Why does one not need a sign in whereas the other does?

[image: OneDrive - Person appears twice.]

Comment: check whether one drive pro installed aside from your one drive client and app

Comment: When I search `OneDrive` in Programs and Features, only one listing displays. So, it appears that I do not have the Pro installed.

Comment: @sunk818 When I cancel out, it doesn't get rid of the duplicate. I wonder where the list of sign ins is kept. Then I could delete it that way.

Comment: @sunk818 Indeed there are two entries. Deleting one of them did not remove the entry in the Save As dialog.

Comment: @sunk818 There is another entry, though, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\ServicesManagerCache\Identities\db5db99f7f8f6191_LiveId` which looks suspicious. It has three entries, two of which are associated with SkyDrive (now OneDrive). Deleting the latter fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Sorry I steered you in the wrong direction.

Comment: @sunk818 You steered me in the right direction! I just had to tweak the path.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was an extra key in the registry. Here are the steps I took to find and remove it:

1. Open any document in MS Word.
2. Choose File > Save As
3. Click on the second OneDrive - Person listing.
4. Click on Sign in in the left hand pane.
5. The expected username will display, e.g.

[image]

1. Open regedit.
2. Choose Edit > Find
3. Select Look at Keys, Values, and Data.
4. Find what:
5. Backup the registry key that's associated with that find result.
6. Then delete the registry key.
7. Reopen word, Save As, and the duplicate entry is no longer there.

The registry key that I deleted.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\ServicesManagerCache\Identities\db5db99f7f8f6191_LiveId\WLMOUNTED_SKYDRIVE_ac337c9a07f40f6f_https://d.docs.live.net/ac337c9a07f40f6f